# How to setup Authorization Hudson /Jenkins to clone your mercurial repository

Tags: configuration, mercurial, hudson, jenkins

After installing and playing around with mercurial , I am trying to get Hudson to clone the repository so it can build my project.

At the moment the following task works.

- I Can sync to my external host and the code shows up on that host.

Now I am trying to configure hudson / jenkins to access the code on my host.

But unfortunately I am rolling on a error:

```
Started by user anonymous
$ hg clone --rev default https://bitbucket.org/*/testproject "F:\Hudson\jobs\testproject\workspace"
abort: http authorization required
ERROR: Failed to clone https://bitbucket.org/*/testproject
[workspace] $ hg log --rev . --template {node}
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "hg" (in directory "F:\Hudson\jobs\testproject\workspace"): CreateProcess error=267, The directory name is invalid
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:460)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:244)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:216)
    at hudson.Launcher$LocalLauncher.launch(Launcher.java:698)
    at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.start(Launcher.java:329)
    at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.join(Launcher.java:336)
    at hudson.plugins.mercurial.MercurialSCM.joinWithPossibleTimeout(MercurialSCM.java:298)
    at hudson.plugins.mercurial.HgExe.popen(HgExe.java:191)
    at hudson.plugins.mercurial.HgExe.tip(HgExe.java:171)
    at hudson.plugins.mercurial.MercurialSCM.calcRevisionsFromBuild(MercurialSCM.java:254)
    at hudson.scm.SCM._calcRevisionsFromBuild(SCM.java:304)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.calcPollingBaseline(AbstractProject.java:1186)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1175)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.checkout(AbstractBuild.java:523)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.run(AbstractBuild.java:418)
    at hudson.model.Run.run(Run.java:1362)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:46)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:145)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=267, The directory name is invalid
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:81)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:30)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:453)
    ... 18 more
Finished: FAILURE
```

What actions do i need to do to tell Hudson to use username x and password y to acces the data?

**Edited** => Found how to integrate ssh .

Comment: could you elaborate please about "Found how to integrate ssh"? I have similar error.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Used SSH instead of https**

Download putty.exe, puttygen.exe, pageant.exe, and plink.exe from the PuTTY website. 
Start puttygen and generate a key in **OPENSSH FORMAT** (hudsons format) (=> [How to use Svn + SSH](http://www.mkyong.com/hudson/how-to-make-hudson-support-svnssh-access/) )

Click the Save private key button and save the .PPK file somewhere.
Click the Save public key button and save it.

Go to your website and enter the public ssh-key

Run pageant.exe. The pageant icon (a computer wearing a hat) will show up in the status tray.

Right-click the pageant icon and choose Add Key.
Choose the .PPK file you saved earlier and type in its passphrase.

The following (end part is copied) from Ted Naleid (Thank you!) blog witch can be found here : [Hooking up hudson to your ...](http://naleid.com/blog/2009/12/21/hooking-up-hudson-to-your-bitbucket-mercurial-account/)

> Install the Mercurial plugin in Hudson
>
> All that’s left to do now is install
>   the Mercurial plugin in hudson. In a
>   browser, go to
>   http://INSERT_YOUR_IP_HERE:8080.
>   Hudson should come up.
>
> Click on “Manage Hudson” and go to
>   “Manage Plugins”. Go to the
>   “Available” tab, check “Hudson
>   Mercurial plugin” and hit the
>   “Install” button. Hudson will prompt
>   you to restart, and then it’s
>   installed.
>
> After that, just create a new job and
>   you’ll have a new “mercurial” option
>   in the “source control management”
>   section. Select that and put the ssh
>   URL in the “Repository URL” field.
>   Then put “default” in the “branch”
>   field and set up the rest of the job
>   to build/test your code (an exercise
>   left to the reader).

and here it is the first succesfull build ! 
[image: First succefull build]

Conclusion : This is a summary of all the small blogpost scattered arround the internet. I hope this post helps you in starting hudson and mercurial.

Answer (score 6):

I think the problem is not related to username and password. Your stacktrace tells you there's something wrong with the path `F:\Hudson\jobs\testproject\workspace`.

> Cannot run program hg (in directory
>   "F:\Hudson\jobs\testproject\workspace")
>
> The directory name is invalid

Anyway, you can specify the username and password in the URL like: `http://user:password@mydomain.org`.

Answer (score 3):

To authenticate the Jenkins/Hudson Mercurial plugin with BitBucket I too found it useful to use the SSH protocol instead of HTTPS particularly since:

1. there doesn't seem to be a way to store your HTTPS credentials to BitBucket with the Mercurial Jenkins plugin, but with SSH you can safely and securely store your credentials
2. with SSH you can configure it to use compression, which Mercurial doesn't do natively.

Good instructions for setting up SSH access to BitBucket are available here:   http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Using+SSH+to+Access+your+Bitbucket+Repository

Notes:

- If you are running Jenkins/Hudson on a *nix server, you will want to login as the user running the Jenkins process and perform these operations from that users home directory, so the configurations will be found by that user (e.g. on my Debian server installation of Jenkins standalone, the user 'jenkins' is created and the home directory is set to '/var/lib/jenkins' [*not* /home/jenkins] - where I performed the instructions provided at the above link).
- I found it very helpful to assure the hg clone command worked from the command line before attempting to have Jenkins call it.
- IMPORTANT: In order to get this to work, I had to generate a key ** without ** a passphrase.

Answer (score 2):

You can add the following lines to jenkins .hgrc file (usually /var/lib/jenkins/.hgrc)

```
[auth]
bitbucket.prefix = https://bitbucket.org/your_user/...
bitbucket.username = your_user
bitbucket.password = ******
```

See http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#auth

Comment: This was the solution for me. On my windows installation the .hgrc file was hidden in this folder if anyone else is looking for it: C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\<your project folder>\.hg If your project folder does not exist here then try do an initial build to get Jenkins to set it up for you.

Comment: The path has changed and is meanwhile jenkins/jobs/<your project folder>/workspace/.hg, but the mercurial plugin got a `Credentials` section, too.

Answer (score 1):

You can add your scm credentials in the 'Credentials` section of Jenkins:

[image]

Also change the job configuration to use the credentials:

[image]